# Can spacy conjugate infinitive verbs?

Tags: spacy

I want to create a tool to assist people with verb conjugation, specifically for the Polish language.

Given an infinitive verb eg. **mieć** (to have) is it possible to use SpaCy to retrieve the first and second person forms of this verb, in this case **mam** (I have) and **masz** (you have)?

I can download and load the Polish model `pl_core_news_sm` using `spacy.load`. `token.lemma_` accurately identifies **mam** and **masz** as the same lemma and the "person" information is available in `token.morph` - but is there a way to do a reverse kind of lookup, i.e given the infinitive find the conjugated forms?

I had started looking at the `Matcher` class and creating a pattern like `[{"LEMMA": infinitive_verb}]` but I am not sure how to do this kind of lookup.

Comment: You do not need SpaCy since it is not designed to do what you want. `morfeusz` or similar morphological analyser libraries can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not Polish, but as I know one popular library for Polish language processing is `morfeusz2`, and you can use `morfeusz2` in combination with SpaCy very easy.

so,let me explain it with a an example as I told, my code will use the `morfeusz2` to analyze the infinitive verb and get the base form (or lemma) of the verb,after that,it creates this neat pattern for SpaCy's Matcher class using that base form,and it goes ahead and matches that pattern against the infinitive verb using SpaCy. at the end it grabs those conjugated forms from the matched tokens.

ok,first of all install it like this:

```
pip install morfeusz2
```

and this is a simple example :

```
import spacy
import morfeusz2

#you can load polish language model in SpaCy like this
nlp = spacy.load("pl_core_news_sm")

morfeusz = morfeusz2.Morfeusz()

#your verb
infinitive_verb = "mieć"

#analyze infinitive verb using Morfeusz2
analysis = morfeusz.analyse(infinitive_verb)

base_form = analysis[0][2][1]

pattern = [{"LEMMA": base_form}]

doc = nlp(infinitive_verb)
matcher = spacy.matcher.Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("VerbConjugation", [pattern])
matches = matcher(doc)

conjugated_forms = []
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    matched_token = doc[start:end]
    conjugated_forms.append(matched_token.text)

# conjugated forms
print(conjugated_forms)
```

powodzenia, mój przyjacielu!

Comment: Looks like morfeuz can help me here, thank you!